# Inserting data into relational table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three relational tables and here is i want to do.

1. insert data into table
2. Get the last inserted row id
3. Insert the last inserted row id into the relational tables

I get this error: Invalid column name LastInsertID

```
 Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    cn.Open()

    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ParentInformation(father_firstname,father_lastname,father_mi,father_occupation " _
                                         & " father_telnum,mother_firstName,mother_lastname,mother_mi,mother_occupation,mother_telnum," _
                                         & " contact_firstname, contact_lastname,contact_MI, contact_Address, contact_telnum) " _
                                         & " VALUES('" & txtFatherGN.Text & "', '" & txtFatherLN.Text & "','" & txtFatherMI.Text & "'," _
                                         & " '" & txtFatherOccupation.Text & "','" & txtFatherCP.Text & "','" & txtMotherGN.Text & "' ," _
                                         & " '" & txtMotherLN.Text & "','" & txtMotherMI.Text & "','" & txtMotherOccupation.Text & "'," _
                                         & "'" & txtMotherCP.Text & "','" & txtContactGN.Text & "','" & txtContactLN.Text & "'," _
                                         & "'" & txtContactMI.Text & "', '" & txtContactAddress.Text & "','" & txtContactCP.Text & "'; dim lastInsertedID as string = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())", cn)
    End Using
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO studentInformation(Surname,firstName, " _
                                          & " MiddleName,Address,Birthday,Gender,Nationality,Birthplace, " _
                                          & " Telnum,SchoolLastAttended,Note,Image,ParentID) " _
                                          & " VALUES('" & txtStudLN.Text & "', '" & txtStudFN.Text & "','" & txtStudMN.Text & "'," _
                                          & " '" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & dtpBirthday.Text & "','" & newStudent & "' ," _
                                          & " '" & cboNationality.Text & "','" & txtPlaceOfBirth.Text & "','" & txtStudentCP.Text & "'," _
                                          & "'" & cboSchoolYear.Text & "','" & cboGradeLevel.Text & "','" & txtSWG.Text & "'," _
                                          & "'" & txtSchoolAddress.Text & "', '" & txtNote.Text & "',@StudentPic,lastInsertedID;dim lastInsertedID as string = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())", cn)

    End Using
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StudentHistory(SchoolYear,Levels,Section,DateEnrolled ,StudentID) " _
                                          & " VALUES('" & cboSchoolYear.Text & "','" & cboGradeLevel.Text & "', " _
                                          & "'" & cboSection.Text & "','" & dtpEnrollment.Text & "', lastInsertedID)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StudentPic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Save " & i & "Record Successfully")
            'clear()
        End If

    End Using


    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

[Relationship of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4vhJ.png)

Can anyone help me to fix this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
,lastInsertedID;dim lastInsertedID as string = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

with

```
,LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

the database server will understand the last value of LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: i got this error now..  Last_INSERT_ID is not recognized built-function name

Comment: With this line of code [code] i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery [/code]